# Detect if function associated with f11, ctrl + up, or ctrl + down are executed in osx using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to detect if function associated with f11, ctrl + up, or ctrl + down are executed (like brining up all the windows) in osx using javascript?

I am not interested in detecting specific keys (and from my experience it isn't possible to detect shortcuts handled by os anyway), but looking for event listeners or any other method that would indicate that that function is in use or was triggered.

What I tried:

- Checking mouse position (it doesn't update)
- Using HTML5 visibility property (document.hidden returns false)
- Using mouseleave event with window (it isn't triggered)
- Checking height and width of the browser window (doesn't change)
- Checking if window is in focus using document.hasFocus()

Am I missing something and do you have any suggestions, or is it considered impossible to achieve?